# Mysql query to fetch/store records in a specific month

Tags: mysql

I have this module where i am supposed to check the winners of bidding in the current month. be that October, November, December or whatever.

I run this query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM auction_winners 
WHERE MONTH('2015-10-16 00:00:00')
```

but it shows me everything, from all the months. 
i believe even if this query works it will work for October only, i am looking for something that checks system current date month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your column with date:

```
SELECT * FROM auction_winners WHERE MONTH(column_name) = MONTH('2015-10-16 00:00:00')
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM auction_winners WHERE MONTH(column_name) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Comment: Yes, and this returns results for october ONLY. i want this to work for every month,

Comment: @FaizanShah So you want all dates or current month, decide?

Comment: @FaizanShah Great to hear I can help